# What should I do if I've solved an issue for myself and think it would be good to have out there?

Tags: discussion, best-practice

I just spent a few minutes trying to figure out how to easily use the keyboard to split the screen between two windows (turns out I needed the Compiz Grid plugin from compiz-fusion-plugins-extra). I also solved a couple of little related issues, like how to properly maximize a window, which the Grid plugin didn't do.

This is good information that I'd love to contribute, and should be out there, but I can't really just make a question and answer it myself, can I? I don't get the impression sockpuppeting is really kosher on stack sites.

Is there any good way of handling this kind of situation?

Comment: I don't understand how the word "sockpuppet" applies to a person answering their own question. It is not possible to vote up a question or answer posted from the same account.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can answer your own question.  It's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

From the [faq](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

> Please look around to see if your
>   question has already been asked (and
>   maybe even answered!) before you ask.
>   It's also perfectly fine to ask and
>   answer your own question, as long as
>   you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase
>   it in the form of a question.

Comment: :D "as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy", love this formulation

Comment: I've seen the FAQ, but someone who's used Stack Overflow for a while, I have to say that sockpuppeting my own question just doesn't feel right. I know the platform is outside of your control, but it would be nice if there were a separate category of "question" that would be a fully-transparent way of passing knowledge on to the community.

Comment: @Grant Why not just try it an mark it CW? We're only a week out of launching we're still establishing how we do things here so I suppose we can just try it and see if it works out?

Comment: @Grant - don't create a new account - just use the same account to answer your question.